# Change Multiple "Sample Products to Variable Product"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a easy way to change the Product Data type for 1,000 Products from **"Sample Products"** to **"Variable Products"** ?

In the WordPress > Woocommerce > Under Products Tab > Filter the required category of products and choose Bulk Edit.

I do not see an option to change the "**Product Date Type**" from Sample Products to Variable Products.

Is there a easy way to do it for multiple products?

Comment: Not via the admin. You would also need to create the product's variations. you *might* be able to program something if you knew what the variations had to look like.

Comment: @helgatheviking, For a variation Product, i upload these informations. 1. Product Title, Product Discription, Featured Image, linked products, Under Variation section: Regular Price, weight (kg), Dimensions, and two global attributes "Color" and "distance"...

Comment: You would need to create all the variations. Ex: Red Short, Red Medium, Red Long, Blue Short, and so on. At least that's just a guess.